# How long should "rake routes" run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rake

I just started out with Rails, so excuse my fairly basic question. I am already noticing that the `rake routes` command takes a while to execute everytime I run it. I have about 20 routes for 3 controllers and it takes about 40 seconds to execute.

Is that normal? How could I speed this up?

P.S.: I am on Windows 7 with Rails 3.1.3 (set up with Rails Installer).

Comment: Is it just rake routes that takes a while? Is it slow to start your server or the console too?

Comment: Better u can check the routes for the particular controller CONTROLLER=controllername rake routes

Comment: @Jan: server (about 1:15 min) and console (0:45 min) also take a while

Comment: if you have the server running, purposefully get a routing error and you can get your routes from there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rake routes task depends on the environment task which loads your Rails environment and requires thousands of Ruby files.

The startup time of a Rails environment and the corresponding rake routes execution time are very close (on my Linux on-steroids-laptop with a Rails application with ~ 50 routes):

```
$ time ruby -r./config/environment.rb -e ''

real    0m5.065s
user    0m4.552s
sys 0m0.456s

$ time rake routes

real    0m4.955s
user    0m4.580s
sys 0m0.344s
```

There is no easy way to decrease startup time as it relies on the way your interpreter requires script files : http://rhnh.net/2011/05/28/speeding-up-rails-startup-time

Comment: My measures are very high for the 'real' part. I am highly sure that can be decreased. My colleagues working with the same application under Ubuntu do get almost immediate result invoking rails or rake.

real 0m26.287s
user 0m3.668s
sys 0m1.672s

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution to `rake routes` taking about 8 seconds to run every time. It's a simple file based cache that runs `bundle exec rake routes`, stores the output in a file under tmp. The filename is the md5 hash of `config/routes.rb`, so if you make a change and change it back, it will use the old cached file.

I put the following bash functions in an executable file I call `fastroutes`:

```
if [ ! -f config/routes.rb ]; then
  echo "Not in root of rails app"
  exit 1
fi

cached_routes_filename="tmp/cached_routes_$(md5 -q config/routes.rb).txt"

function cache_routes {
  bundle exec rake routes > $cached_routes_filename
}

function clear_cache {
  for old_file in $(ls tmp/cache_routes*.txt); do
    rm $old_file
  done
}

function show_cache {
  cat $cached_routes_filename
}

function show_current_filename {
  echo $cached_routes_filename
}

function main {
  if [ ! -f $cached_routes_filename ]; then
    cache_routes
  fi

  show_cache
}

if [[ "$1" == "-f" ]]
then
  show_current_filename 
elif [[ "$1" == "-r" ]]
then
  rm $cached_routes_filename
  cache_routes
else
  main
fi
```

Here's a [github link](https://github.com/tlehman/bin/blob/master/fastroutes) too.

This way, you only have to generate the routes once, and then `fastroutes` will used the cached values.

Answer (score 0):

That seems a bit long, but do you really need to run `rake routes` that often? On my system, OSX Lion/Rails 3.2.0, `rake routes` takes ~10s.

Comment: At least initially while trying to get a grasp of the concept I had the feeling I will have to ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In your Rakefile:

```
#Ouptut stored output of rake routes
task :fast_routes => 'tmp/routes_output' do |t|
   sh 'cat', t.source
end

#Update tmp/routes_output if its older than 'config/routes.rb'
file 'tmp/routes_output' => 'config/routes.rb' do |t|
  outputf = File.open(t.name, 'w')
  begin
     $stdout = outputf
     Rake.application['routes'].invoke
  ensure
     outputf.close
     $stdout = STDOUT
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Rails environment takes a huge more amount of time to be loaded on Windows. I recommend you to give Unix a try, like Ubuntu, as Windows is the worst environment in which you can run and develop Ruby on Rails applications. But if you are just trying Rails, Windows is enough :)

Comment: You are meant to run `rake routes` or it wouldn't be available as a Rake task. If the OP is just starting out w/ Rails, the routes task is likely helpful to them to understand the routes that are setup automatically.

Comment: I run rake routes all the time because I find it easier to figure out what a route is translated to.

Comment: rake routes task is very useful when beginning with Rails. I am not a beginner but often use that task, actually whenever I need to review I18n translations of routes.

Comment: I am aware that Win is not the best platform to do this, but I had hoped for my first steps it would do (as you said, it should be enough for trying). Will consider switching over to Linux though if this might become a more permanent thing.

Comment: On Ubuntu now, it's muuuuuuuuuuuch faster ... ;-)